# required: boolean found: int 1 error

Tags: java

I don't understand why I am receiving the error:

`GuessingGame.java:15: error: incompatible types`

My Code:

```
for (numberOfTries=0; numberOfTries = 4; numberOfTries++){
}
```

`required: boolean`

`found:    int`

`1 error`

when numberOfTries is of type `int` and so is 4

Comment: What is this for loop???

Comment: You need to take a Java tutorial. `=` is used for assignment, not equality testing (which would be `==`), and I think you meant to iterate up to it, which means you want either `<` or `<=`.

Comment: '==' for comparisons.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here are some formatting tips: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thanks for the clarification i fixed it thanks @bcsb1001

Comment: yes it was for loop @bmarkham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever initialize `numberOfTries`?

Try changing this:

```
 for (numberOfTries=0; numberOfTries = 4; numberOfTries++){
```

To:

```
 for (int numberOfTries=0; numberOfTries <= 4; numberOfTries++){
```

Comment: The problem is due to the middle statement is not returning `boolean`.

Comment: ah sorry @JohnD I'm new to this I just learned how to do this